# make install generates file exists error

Tags: makefile

I am trying to compile and create an executable of this [tool](https://github.com/scribd/advancecomp/tree/master/src), did a ./configure and then make and then make install, however during the process I got this error:

```
test -z "/usr/local/bin" || ./install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/bin"
mkdir: /usr/local/bin: File exists
make[1]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Is there any chance that you have a file (as opposed to directory) called `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, wouldn't an existing directory `/usr/local/bin` cause the same error?

Comment: @Beta: maybe, but the invocation is supposed to create the directory if it doesn't exist (I think) so it shouldn't complain if it is a directory.  But it is a guess...I've not tried it (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a *file* named `/usr/local/bin`. Remove it like so:

```
rm /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Try running `mkdir foobar` twice. The second time, I get `mkdir: foobar: File exists`.